# Hiding Health Bar Until Enemy is nearby C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hidden

I know how to create a collider to detect a game object tagged as "Enemy". I'm also familiar with making it an isTrigger event as well as the functionality of OnTriggerEnter().

What my problem seem to be is reading the image from my Health Point Script(HPsc) into my EnemyDetection script.

In my HPsc I've declared and assigned my HP images (red and green) as public static Image HP_Green, HP_Red. So in my EnemyDetection script I reference these HPsc.HP_Green.SetActive(True) and HPsc.HP_Red.SetActive(true)

However, the problem seem to be that SetActive is for text UI and not for Image? 
Could FadeIn() and FadeOut() actually be an alternative here?

HealthBar Class:

```
public class HPsc
{
    public static Image HP_Bar_Green;
    public static Image HP_Bar_Red; // Allows me to initialize the images in Unity

    void Start()
    {
        HP_Bar_Green = GetComponent<Image>();
        HP_Bar_Red = GetComponent<Image>(); //How I grab the images upon startup
    }
}
```

EnemyDetection:

```
public class EnemyDetection
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy1")
        {
            HpSc.HP_Bar_Green.SetActive(true);
            // This is DetectEnemy trying to grab the image from the other script.
        }
    }
}
```

***** SOLUTION ISSUE #1 *****
HP_Bar_Green.gameObject.SetActive(true); – Fredrik Widerberg

Just needed to string the gameObject in there! Thanks all!

****** ISSUE #2 ******
Ok, now my next issue with this code is getting BOTH images into the correct variables.

HP_Bar_Green = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent();
HP_Bar_Red = transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.GetComponent();

I'm trying to insure that each variable can only contain what its supposed to. .GetChild() looks promosing but it is causing a lot of issues. The compiler allows the game to start and play, but over 5 minutes I stacked up 20,000 identical errors in the compiler.

***** Issue is RESOLVED *****

Hallelujah!

I moved HP_Bar_Red into my EnemyDetection script. Made it a public variable and manually inserted the object inside Unity inspector. (As a few people have been recommending here. Thanks to you all! Stay blessed!)

Comment: I believe to hide and unhide gui components you have to perform it on their canvas renderers.

Comment: You need to show the code you are using, the explanation are not really helping.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I'm not sure how to properly add the images and/or code... Perhaps I'll have to ask stacked that too? smh lol Anyway, reallly quick, how do I insert the C# so you can see it clean?

Comment: What is the definition of HP_Bar_Green? Im guessing you need to do HP_Bar_Green.gameObject.SetActive(true);

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are trying to do `SetActive()` on a `Image` component.
However, `SetActive()` is a part of `GameObject` to activate/deactivate the `GameObject` in your hierachy.

So you need to get the `GameObject` first, and call `SetActive()` on it

```
myImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

If you want to enable/disable just the `Image`-component you could do

```
myImage.enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the GameObject on the Image component to be active or inactive using

```
GameObject.SetActive(boolean)
```

Or Alternatively you could do this

```
HpSc.HP_Bar_Green.enabled = true/false;
```

Class:

```
public class EnemyDetection
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy1")
        {
            HpSc.HP_Bar_Green.GameObject.SetActive(true);
            //or
            HpSc.HP_Bar_Green.enabled = true;
            // This is DetectEnemy trying to grab the image from the other script.
        }
    }
}
```

You might run into issue with having the HpSc.HP_Bar_Green being static so if there are multiple enemies you might want to have a class that gets the HpSc component and disables it for that specific one.

```
public class EnemyDetection
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy1")
        {
            HpSc healthBar = other.GetComponent<HpSc>();

            healthBar.GameObject.SetActive(true);
            //or
            healthBar.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Non Static variables:

```
public class HPsc
{
    public Image HP_Bar_Green;
    public Image HP_Bar_Red; // Allows me to initialize the images in Unity

    void Start()
    {
        HP_Bar_Green = this.GetComponent<Image>();
        HP_Bar_Red = this.GetComponent<Image>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the thorough response! I actually have a couple new ways of approaching things now! Very cool! My new question for you is that ya mentioned there may be a problem due to my static declaration. What would you recommend me changing them to if not static?

Comment: have them be public. If it is static, then across any instance of that class (on multiple enemies) there will be the same reference to the health bar. So I would make a prefab for your enemy objects and drag and drop that healthbar image into the image variable on the component in the inspector. Then you could spawn multiple enemies, each enemy would reference their own helathbar and then you could go with the second option I threw up there. You can drag components into public variables in Unity. Also you should say this.GetComponent<Image>() as red and green will reference the same image.

Comment: Okay, so I've been trying to implement your suggestion but I'm running into a few different issues.

Comment: First, I have to put the script on both of my images before they'll respond. The program gets 4 imgs evertime I run the game. (2 for each img). However, neither is reading into the OnTriggerEnter nor Exit function. Regardless if I manually enter the images through the Unity inspector. Each time I run the program, it seems to override the components that I've manually inserted. Yet I'm getting a NullRefernce error message upon entering and exiting the trigger. Is this an Inheritance issue?

Comment: One last thing. When I created my health bar, I created an EMPTY and put the bar images there. I did not connect them to my player as a child.

Comment: Make sure that the images still have a reference and exist when you run the Game in the editor, if they are automatically generated make sure that they are assigned appropriately.